# Search .msg files on network drive for a keyword

Tags: powershell

I am required to search 25000 individual .msg files on a network drive for a keyword. I have created scripts for Word, Excel, PDFs but I am stuck on Outlook message files (.msg). I need the script to read a .msg file, find the keyword, then if the keyword is in the .msg file, copy the file to another folder. I have googled and have not found the help I need.

I have tried adding `Get-Content`, `Select-String -Pattern` but I get errors that I can't figure out.

This is as close as I have gotten.

```
Get-ChildItem "y:\test" -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object {
        $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
        $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($_.FullName)
        $msg | Select body | ft -AutoSize
    }
```

This finds my test .msg file. It displays the body and I can see the keyword. Now I need the rest.

Comment: Is powershell a requeriment? Are python or php an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. `$msg` is just a long string, so you can use a simple `-like` match to see if it contains your keyword:

```
Get-ChildItem "y:\test" -Filter *.msg |
ForEach-Object{
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($_.FullName)
    $msg | Select body|ft -AutoSize

    if($($msg | Select -ExpandProperty body) -like "*keyword*"){
        # logic to copy file
    }
}
```

Comment: Milage may vary but I would guess having `$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application` in the loop would be a performance waste.